# Closest point on a line segment from point outside the line

Tags: google-maps, intersection, point-in-polygon

[image]

From the above pic I found the value **x** from line (p1,p2) and point **a**.

Using `y=mx+b` and an imaginary red line which is perpendicular to the black line having slope **-1/m**

and the intersecting point **x**, the problem is that **x** is not actually intersecting.

See pic below

[image]

Comment: What software are you using to get the location of `x`? How far off the line is `x` falling?

Comment: I am using Google map. the point x is calculated by mathematical formula.when map zoom in to the deepest location I found that two lines are not intersecting.I thing the points contain large precisions

Comment: The mismatch is probably caused by insufficient decimal accuracy during the calculation, and/or in Google Map's rendering of the location.

Comment: If it cause by math problem any solution ? Erica ...

Comment: The precision can be increased by using more decimals, but is not likely to ever be perfect. At some point, Google will be the problem -- e.g., you upload a point with 100 decimal places, they will simply round it off to less.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for python and return a qgisPoint:

```
def nearestPoint(A, B, p):
    A0 = A[0]
    A1 = A[1]
    B0 = B[0]
    B1 = B[1]
    p0 = p[0]
    p1 = p[1]
    AB0 = B0-A0
    AB1 = B1-A1
    AB_squared = (AB0*AB0+AB1*AB1)+0.0
    if (AB_squared == 0):
        return A
    else:
        Ap0 = p0-A0
        Ap1 = p1-A1
        t = (Ap0*AB0+Ap1*AB1)/AB_squared
        if (t<0):
            return (A0,A1);
        elif (t>1):
            return (B0,B1);
        else:
            return QgsPoint(A0+t*AB0,A1+t*AB1)
```

AB are from the line segment and p is the point of interest

Comment: this is shortest or longest ?

Comment: It is the shortest.